# How to change a color using chrome console

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make changes using Chrome's console, something similar to inspecting and changing a value, e.g. `color:red` to `color:black`

I have an extension to Chrome that makes it possible to save an inspect element forever, but to do that I have to write a code like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hello")[number of column for example].style
```

I don't know how to change color of this line:

```html
<td class="tabWartosc2" style=""><span style="color:red"><small><b>1.
</b>
</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;Blahblax</span><br><span style="color:red"><small><b>2.</b>
</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;Xyzs</span><br><span style="color:red"><small><b>3.</b>
</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ples</span><br><span style="color:red"><small><b>4.</b></small>&nbsp;&nbsp;Bobo</span><br><span style="color:red"><small><b>5.</b></small>&nbsp;&nbsp;Bonjour</span><br><span style="color:red"><small><b>6.</b>
```

That's how it looks in Chrome's inspect window. How can I change the `style color red` in the way that I have it?

```
(document.getElementsByClassName("tabWartosc2")
```

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('. tabWartosc2 > span').style()` or `document.getElementsByClassName('tabWartosc2'). getElementsByTagName('span').style()`

Comment: @Jake on the first command i have VM5687:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '. tabWartosc2 > span' is not a valid selector.
    at <anonymous>:1:10

Comment: Then the issue is on your end. Tested with your snippet, `document.querySelectorAll('.tabWartosc2 > span')` returns all 6 spans. **Edit** : you have a space between the class dot and tabWartosc2...

Comment: Looks like you had a capital "D" for document, it needs to be lower case

Comment: I'm, not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to change an element's color via the `console`?

Comment: @Jake `style` is a property, not a method. There shouldn't be parentheses. Also, the `getElementsBy*` functions return lists, so you can't call methods or get properties on them (except if they are methods or properties of lists).

Comment: @MoshFeu yes i want to change elements color which is a text (spanstyle) from red to black ..

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('span')[1].style.color = 'black';` https://jsbin.com/tevipiq/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @HereticMonkey, you're completely right, didn't pay attention.. A for loop or forEach will be necessary either when using getElementsByClassName or when using querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML I can't see a clear structure right now so I answer a bit broader:

Tint all spans on page:

```
let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('span');
for(let node of nodes) node.style.color = "black";
```

Tint all spans on page that have a red color:

```
let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('span');
for(let node of nodes) if(node.style.color == "red") node.style.color = "black";
```

Tint all spans on page that are in a `<td>` tag:

```
let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('td span');
for(let node of nodes) node.style.color = "black";
```

Hope that helps you

Comment: On your last option you're missing 'td span' if you intend to target only spans that are in a td element.